# Не работает PostProcessing c Lightweight RP 2D и Cinemachine 2D Unity

Tags: unity3d

В общим схема такая: я подключил 2D Lightweight и теперь на PipeLine у меня стоит 2D рендеринг, а камера управляется с помощью Cinemachine и к ней мне нужно применить постоброботку (PostProcessing  из ассетов).

Я попробовал добавить профайл пост-обработки к виртуальной камере

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но эффекты не отображались ни в игре ни в редакторе. Потом я повесил на основную камеру postprocessing layer что так же не дало результата.

Потом я добавил на сену volume объект (volume>global volume), я так полагаю что это объекты из Lightweight. Выглядел он так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И самое интересное то, что эффект отобразился но только в редакторе, в окне игры он по прежнему не работал

Я бы хотел узнать как правильно применить пост-оброботку в 2д ну или как работает cinemachine и как её заставить отображать пост-оброботку, которая применяется к обычной камере

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил через vulume объекты.
Оказывается камера по дефолту на рендерит пост-обработку по этому её нужно самостоятельно включить в главной камере Camera>Rendering>Post-Processing
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]